# yaml file issue Unexpected value 'steps', "mapping values are not allowed in this context", trying to create jobs using template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, cicd

in my main YAML

```
stages:
  - stage: ui_tests
    <.......>

  - stage: ui_remote_testing
    jobs:
      - template: status-template.yml
        parameters:
          polls: [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ]
```

in my status-template.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: "polls"
    type: object
    default: { }

steps:
  -job: polling_job
    - ${{ each poll in parameters.polls }}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $global:testsCompleted = 0
```

what do I need to change to make the template run as jobs

Answer (score 0):

Steps come within Jobs, not the other way around, so the template should be:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: polling_job
  steps:
  - ${{ each poll in parameters.polls }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $global:testsCompleted = 0
```